# Create multple object files at once without using a makefile?

Tags: gcc, object-files

When I try

```
gcc -c *.c
```

I get an invalid argument error, and it says no input files.

Comment: What OS are you compiling on?

Comment: I need more information, because your problem doesn't present in my computer(ubuntu 14.04 with default gcc and shell), it totally works fine.
what OS and shell are you using?

Comment: Im using MinGW with gcc 4.8.1 on windows 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run `gcc` from a directory where no C source files are present, `gcc` will receive the `*.c` argument unexpanded, will try to open a file named `*.c` and fail, will report this failure and in the absence of further arguments, will complain about the missing input files:

```
$ gcc -c *.c
gcc: error: *.c: No such file or directory
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
$
```

The wildcard expansion is performed by the command line interpreter, aka the shell. On a unix system, there are many different shells, sh, csh, tcsh, bash, zsh... all of which expand unquoted wildcards before running the commands.  On Windows, the default shells do not expand wildcards for external commands, some programs do it on their own, but most don't.  If you run bash on Windows, with or without cygwin, you will get the Unix behavior, but if you run cmd.exe, you won't.

MinGW is a set of development tools to make Windows native executables. It does not provide a shell and favors using the native libraries and utilities when possible.  This is the reason why your command `gcc -c *.c` does not undergo wildcard expansion on your machine.  Install bash or cygwin for a more unix-friendly environment.

Comment: There are multiple C files present in my directory, obviously. When I try the code with gcc -c file1.c file2.c..(so on), it seems to work fine, but not with *.c.

Comment: gcc -c $(echo *.c)

Comment: @Sashank: If you are running the `gcc -c *.c` command from a Windows shell such as `cmd.exe`, the file expansion does not necessarily take place.  Use `bash` from `cygwin` in this case.

Comment: @forvaidya: I doubt `echo` would expand the wildcards if the shell does not.  You might try `gcc -c $(glob *.c)`, but we don't know what kind of shell the OP is using.

Comment: @chqelie The command works fine when I use bash for windows. Why should it work with the linux gnu and not with mingw32?

Comment: @Sashank:  MinGW32 does not provide a shell.  See my updated answer.

Comment: @chqrlie Thanks so much for the explanation. I also got it to work using MinGW on Powershell with `gcc -c (dir *.c)`. But is there a way to pipe the output of the wildcard expansion of dir *.c to the input of gcc?

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you're looking for.

find . -name '*.c' -print | xargs gcc -c